# how to disable some fields from dropdownchecklist in jquery

Tags: asp.net

I have a listbox with some datasouce attached to it, and i have made it as a dropdowncheklist using jquery.
now i want to disable some of the checkboxes in list according to my dataset return through my select query.
could you plz help me out..
I am binding data to listbox by following code:

```
        Lb_MultiClient.Items.Clear();
        Lb_MultiClient.Items.Add("All");     
        Lb_MultiClient.DataSourceID = "SqlDS_ClientProj";
        Lb_MultiClient.DataTextField = "ClientProj_idname";
        Lb_MultiClient.DataValueField = "Client_Project_Id";
        Lb_MultiClient.DataBind();
```

my aspx code for hat listbox is as follows:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="Lb_MultiClient" runat="server" Height="22px" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        Width="210px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:ListBox>
```

My jquery code for this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#Lb_MultiClient").dropdownchecklist( { onItemClick: function(checkbox) {
        },firstItemChecksAll: true, explicitClose: '...close' , emptyText: str , width: 200 } );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx) property of [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) class.

Comment: .enabled property of listbox does not work for this case as it removes item from listbox not disable. and i also want to make that perticular chechbox as checked at d same tym.